# How to identify a role with a tag in Spring security?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

Is it possible to identify the user role with a tag in spring security? I want to make different links depending on the user role, an admin should get other links than a user and maybe view an altogether different jsp page. Can you tell me how to know user role with a tag e.g. output depending on role?

I have these roles:

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/admin/menu**" access="ROLE_USER" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/admin/manage**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

But how can I change the routing depending on who is who? I suppose a way to do it is to set the role as a variable at login and then read it with JSP so that I can output one menu for a `ROLE_USER` and another for `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Spring Security has a JSTL library you can import that has all sorts of nice little tools.  The Docs for it can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html).

Specifically, you want to do something like:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  <!-- Some optional code here -->
</sec:authorize>
```

This will execute the items in between the tags if the user has the role 'ROLE_ADMIN'.